# Why does .Send return a Run-time error: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response?

Tags: excel, vba, database, server

I have a report that considers inputs via dropdown menus linked to some databases e.g., customer, and currency...

After inputs are selected it generates a report based on these inputs, the data I have and through the VBA code.

Today I have an error message on `.send request_str`.

> Run-time error '-2147012744 (80072f78)': The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response

```vb
Public Sub send_post_request()

    'This function sends the JSON generated by get_inputs by a POST request to the web service hosted on host_url

'    Dim wb As Workbook
'    Dim ws As Worksheet
'    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
'    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Output")

    'get the JSON to send
    request_str = get_inputs()

'    ws.Range("A1").Value = request_str

    'creates a new HTTP server object
    Dim HTTP_object As Object
    Set HTTP_object = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    
    With HTTP_object
    
        'set timeout on HTTP response
        .setTimeouts 30000, 30000, 30000, -1
    
        'starts a POST request
        .Open "POST", host_url & tool_url_path, False
    
        'sets headers
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    
        'sends the request
        .send request_str

'        waits for response from server
'        .waitForResponse
'
'        writes server response to worksheet
'        ws.Range("A1").Value = .ResponseText

        'gets the HTTP response status and shows the result of the request
        Status = .StatusText
        If Status = "OK" Then
            msg_text = "Report successfully generated."
            MsgBox msg_text, vbInformation, tool_name
        Else
            msg_text = "Report not generated. Please check your inputs and try again." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "If the error persists, please contact: [email]TPICAPCRMSolutions@tpicap.com[/email]"
            MsgBox msg_text, vbExclamation, tool_name
        End If
    
    End With

End Sub
```

I checked the inputs via 'Add Watches'. Everything is fine.
I ran another file that is very similar in a way of inputs and from where the data is from (same thing) and this one runs perfectly well. It uses the same method and same code to send the request to server.

Comment: I had the same error code and it turned out that the problem is in the response from the server.  In my case, the response included corrupted headers that did not match the HTTP header format, so the parsing of the response threw the error.